# Passing variable values to next stage implemented in yaml template

Tags: templates, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I need to set variable values at runtime in my main template before it calls a stage yaml template.

In my current working setup I define the variable value inside the stage yaml template by referencing a previous stage that is residing in the main template. This is clearly an undesired mixture of concerns:

- The stage template should never know anything about anything outside its input parameters;
- And, the main template should never know the variable names inside the stage template.

Is there a way to provide the variable values in the main template cleanly?

Current working example:

main template:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: prepStage
  jobs:
  - job: prepJob
    steps:
    - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      name: MyCheckStep
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: mysubscription
        ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
        Inline: |
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CheckValue;isOutput=true]MyValue"
        azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
- template: test_template.yaml
  parameters:    
    Environment: $(CheckValueFromPreviousStage)
    Environment2: $[ stageDependencies.prepStage.prepJob.outputs['MyCheckStep.CheckValue'] ]
```

Stage template

```yaml
parameters:
- name: Environment
  type: string
- name: Environment2
  type: string

stages:
- stage: MyDecisionStage
  dependsOn: prep
  variables:
    CheckValueFromPreviousStage: $[ stageDependencies.prepStage.prepJob.outputs['MyCheckStep.CheckValue'] ]
  jobs:   
  - job: myJob
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo $(CheckValueFromPreviousStage)
        echo "Environment: ${{ parameters.Environment }}"
        echo "Environment2: ${{ parameters.Environment2 }}"
```

This yields:

`MyValue`
`Environment: MyValue`
`/home/vsts/work/_temp/4570001c-b86b-4f0b-987c-356b70a9c07e.sh: line 3: stageDependencies.prep.prep.outputs['MyCheckStep.CheckValue'] : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".prepStage.prepJob.outputs['MyCheckStep.CheckValue'] ")`

Answer (score 0):

What about write the MyDecisionStage part into the main yaml?

main yml

```
stages:
- stage: prepStage
  jobs:
  - job: prepJob
    steps:
    - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      name: MyCheckStep
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: ***
        ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
        Inline: |
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CheckValue;isOutput=true]MyValue"
        azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
- stage: MyDecisionStage
  dependsOn: prepStage
  variables:
    CheckValueFromPreviousStage: $[ stageDependencies.prepStage.prepJob.outputs['MyCheckStep.CheckValue'] ]
  jobs:   
  - job: myJob
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
       targetType: 'inline'
       script: Write-Host "$(CheckValueFromPreviousStage)"
    - template: test_template.yaml
      parameters:    
       Environment: $(CheckValueFromPreviousStage)
```

test_template.yaml

```
parameters:
- name: Environment
  type: string
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
   targetType: 'inline'
   script: Write-Host "output1 - ${{ parameters.Environment }}"
```

[image]